# Dual-booting on one partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I have been doing some research for a while on dual booting, often when I see pages or documentation on it, they have several partitions, and I have one. The one partition I have is ext4, it has plenty of room. But it's mounted, I spent all my money on buying windows 10 to dual boot with my Ubuntu GNOME, IT would be great if I could resize it without mounting it? If you can do it safely with it mounted then I will be happy to do that, if it would be less of a struggle and risk I am open to somehow removing Ubuntu to put windows on. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I want to keep Windows if possible, and I can't dual-bott because I can't resize. The partition is Mounted.

Comment: You can't dual-boot on one partition. You have to resize the ext4 partition after you backup all your data.

Comment: @WhyUDoDis The partition is mounted when you boot it. You just need to boot a live media (CD, USB, …) to be able to resize it. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions for details. Or you can install Windows in a virtual machine.

Comment: I had heard about doing that @Melebius but thought it would be dangerous, I will look into it now. Also, most of the times I wrote partitions I mean Driver haha, I was just confused on how to make multiple! Thank you so mucH!

Comment: @WhyUDoDis You probably mean a [drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive#Technology)? A [drive***r***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) is yet another thing…